# Is there a reasonable one hour summary of Game Theory?

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, book-recommendation, combinatorial-game-theory, online-resources

In his Topology and Geometry course on Youtube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzfZS3iopR0&t=10m7s), Tadashi Tokieda claims he can teach all of game theory in an hour. He seemed very sincere and serious about this claim.

Are there any books/resources about game theory which purport to do this and succeed?

Comment: Glenn Gould [said](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-news/glenn-gould-the-rolling-stone-interview-part-one-180448/)  "everything there is to know about playing the piano can be taught in half an hour" .  Just to say.

Comment: You can also find youtube videos that claim to show perpetual motion. A lot of smart folks have spent entire careers on this subject, right? Can you imagine someone saying that they can explain all of plumbing in an hour? If not, then why game theory?

Comment: It depends what you mean by game theory, I guess. You can instruct someone on the rules of chess and how the pieces move in an hour. That doesn't mean they'll remember it an hour later, or be able to play a good game of chess.

Comment: I generally dismiss claims like this, but Tadashi is a very good Mathematician and Communicator. And so I'm confused. Hence the question. It may not fit the format of this site, but I don't like ignoring "basic confusions".

The only way I know how to interpret his claim is that explaining something like the basic rules of Quantum mechanics, in contrast, is very difficult. So by default I agree with Mark Bennet, but I felt asking a question may still be useful.

Comment: I think he means he can explain the concept of normal form games / dominant strategies / mixed strategy Nash equilibria, etc, which doesn’t strike me as a ridiculous claim. The ridiculous claim is that learning this constitutes learning “all of game theory”. It’s like saying I can teach you all of classical physics in 15 minutes, and then I give you a great explanation of Newton’s laws.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen if you can explain what you mean by "etc." I think your comment would make a good answer to the question. (Maybe even without, I am not strong at game theory).